# IGNORE- Get value of variable from function for use in another function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I know this must have been asked before as it is a very simple question, however I cannot get a clear answer.

How do I get the value of a variable from a function in to another function?

```js
var x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
    x = 1
}

function secondFunc(){
    alert(x);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking... In your actual case, since your variable is globally scoped, it is modifiable and possible to get within both functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like you did. You declared `x` at the scope of the entire script, so other functions can evaluate it.

Calling both functions in the snippet below shows that the variable was changed by function 1 and evaluated with its new value at function 2:

```js
var x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
    x = 1
}

function secondFunc(){
    alert(x);
}
firstFunc();
secondFunc();
```

Comment: Apologies and thank you...realised it was an issue in my other code that was not working. Sorry for wasting your time haha

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the value of "x" across both functions. You are just not calling the functions to prove it.

Take a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) for more information on global variables

```js
var x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
    x = 1
}

function secondFunc(){
    alert(x);
}
firstFunc();
secondFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do that 
one of them is
making the first function return the variable and in the second function you can use this variable

```
var x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
    return x = 1
}

function secondFunc(){
    x= firstFunc();
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't need to return anything because x = 1 is already being defined

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi well , if you removed it and call secondFunc()  x will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to get a local variable declared inside the function scope? if so, one way is to call the function inside a function, so we get the variable declared inside the function scope.

```
x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
   var x = 1;
   secondFunc();
}

function secondFunc(){
   alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are expecting alert should show 1 ?? This already working like that only. Check this link

http://ztoi.blogspot.in/2017/08/get-value-of-variable-from-function-for.html

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you are already able to get the value of the variable `x` across both functions.

This is possible because the `x` is defined as global so it can read and set by both functions.

[Interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) to learn more about js scope.

```js
var x = 0;
function firstFunc(){
    x = 1
}

function secondFunc(){
    alert(x);
}

firstFunc();
secondFunc();
```